# Passing an object between two UserControls and a main Form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

So I have one main Form that works as the navigation bar and two UserControls that display some controls.
In `UserControlsA` I have some fields that require to be filled. With that data I create an Object that contains some information. I require to pass that object to `UserControlsB` so I can display some data there.

My idea was to make three instances of the object, one in the `UserControlsA` to get the information required for the object, one in the main form to get a "copy" of the object from `UserControlsA`, and one in `UserControlsB` that can get the information from the main Form.

However, this seems redundant and doesn't even work. Here's some code:

**Main Form:**

```
public partial class main : Form
{
    public Object object { get; set; }
    public UCA uca;
    public UCB ucb;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        uca = new UCA();
        ucb = new UCB();

        panel2.Controls.Add(uca);
        panel2.Controls.Add(ucb);

        ucb.Visible = false;
        uca.Visible = true;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucb.Visible = false;
        uca.Visible = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucb.Visible = true;
        uca.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

**UserControlsA**:

```
public partial class UCA : UserControl
{
    public Object object { get; set; }
    
    public UCA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bUsage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Data is provided
        object = new Object(data);

        //I use var parent to try and access the object from the main form.
        var parent = Parent as Form1;
        object = parent.object;
    }
 }
```

**UsercontrolB**:

```
public partial class UCB : UserControl
{
    public Object object { get; set; }

    public UCB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void updateData()
    {
        //I try to assign the object from the main form to this form's object.
        var parent = Parent as Form1;
        object = parent.object;
    }
}
```

Using var Parent doesn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of examples using the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) Interface and an implementation that makes use of standard public events.

Related Documentation:
[Windows Forms Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding)
[Change Notification in Windows Forms Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/change-notification-in-windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&redirectedfrom=MSDN)
[Interfaces Related to Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/interfaces-related-to-data-binding)

**Using `INotifyPropertyChanged`**:
The UserControl exposes a public Property (here, named `CustomDataObject`, simple `string` Type in the first example, `object` in the second. It can another Type of course).
The Property is decorated with the [Bindable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindableattribute) attribute. The `BindingDirection` here is more a *description of the intent*, there's no Template attached to it.
Two other standard Attributes are added:

- [DefaultValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute) defines the default value of a Property (the value assigned to the Property when the Control is created). It's used by the Code Generator to determine whether the current value should be serialized: it's not serialized if it matches the value set by the Attribute.
  It's also used by the PropertyGrid to show, in bold, a non-default value selection or assignment.
- [DesignerSerializationVisibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibility) specifies the how the Property should be serialized at design-time. Here, is set to [DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibility), to signify that the Property should be serialized.

The `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface can be seen as a simplified way to add Property bindings to more than one property, using the same event handler, to notify a change in value.
The default implementation of the Interface simply requires that a a public Event of type [PropertyChangedEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventhandler) is added to the class.
When a Property value is changed, the setter just invokes the Event. There are slightly different ways to perform this action; here I'm using a `OnPropertyChanged()` method that uses the [CallerMemberName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute) Attribute to *acquire* the name of the Property that calls it. It's fairly common in both WinForms and WPF.

**UCA UserControl**:
The UserControl (see the visual example), has two Buttons that change the bound `CustomDataObject` Property value. Their `Click` action is handled by  `ButtonsAction_Click`.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class UCA : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string m_DataObject = string.Empty;

    public UCA() => InitializeComponent();

    [Bindable(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay), DefaultValue("")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public string CustomDataObject {
        get => m_DataObject;
        set {
            if (m_DataObject != value){
                m_DataObject = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    private void ButtonsAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = sender as Button;
        CustomDataObject = (btn == SomeButton) ? txtInput1.Text : txtInput2.Text;
    }
}
```

**UCB UserControl**:
This other UserControl is the *receiver*. It just exposes a public Property (`ReceiverDataObject`) that will be bound to the `CustomDataObject` Property of UCA.

The `ReceiverDataObject` property is also defined as `[Bindable]`, with the *intention* of making it one-way only. The property doesn't raise any event. It receive a value, stores it in a private Field and sets an internal UI element.

```
public partial class UCB : UserControl
{
    private string m_RecvDataObject = string.Empty;

    public UCB() => InitializeComponent();

    [Bindable(true, BindingDirection.OneWay)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public string ReceiverDataObject {
        get => m_RecvDataObject;
        set {
            m_RecvDataObject = value;
            txtPresenter.Text = m_RecvDataObject;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Using Standard Events notifications**:
You can also generate Property change notifications using standard Events.
The difference is that you need an Event for each Property that should notify changes.
If you already have Event delegates used for this, then it's probably a good choice, since there's very few to add: just call the protected method that raises the Event in the Property setter.

Here, I'm, using the common .Net Event handling, using the [EventHandlerList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.eventhandlerlist) defined by the underlying Component class and exposed by its [Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component.events) property, to add remove event subscriptions.
The Events are usually raised calling a protected method that has the same name of the Event, except the `On` prefix.
Here, `CustomDataObjectChanged` Event => `OnCustomDataObjectChanged()` method.
You can see this pattern in all standard Controls.

▶ The **`CustomDataObjectChanged`** name assigned to the Event is not a choice: this event must have the same name of the Property and the **`Changed`** suffix.
This is the pattern, it's enough to just follow it.

**UCA UserControl**:

```
public partial class UCA : UserControl
{
    private static readonly object Event_CustomDataObjectChanged = new object();
    private object m_DataObject = null;

    public UCButtonActions() => InitializeComponent();

    [Bindable(BindableSupport.Yes, BindingDirection.TwoWay), DefaultValue(null)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public object CustomDataObject {
        get => m_DataObject;
        set {
            if (m_DataObject != value){
                m_DataObject = value;
                OnCustomDataObjectChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler CustomDataObjectChanged {
        add {
            Events.AddHandler(Event_CustomDataObjectChanged, value);
        }
        remove {
            Events.RemoveHandler(Event_CustomDataObjectChanged, value);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnCustomDataObjectChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Events[Event_CustomDataObjectChanged] is EventHandler evth) evth(this, e);
    }
}
```

**UCB UserControl**:
The second UserControl doesn't change. It's just the receiver.

---

The Form class (or another class used as Handler):

In the Form Constructor, or any other method called after the Form initialization, use the [DataBindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.databindings) property of UCB to link the Properties of the two UserControls:

```
public SomeForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ucb1.DataBindings.Add("ReceiverDataObject", uca1, "CustomDataObject", 
        false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

You can also use a BindingSource to mediate:

```
BindingSource ucsSource = null;

public SomeForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ucsSource = new BindingSource(uca1, null);
    ucb1.DataBindings.Add("ReceiverDataObject", ucsSource, "CustomDataObject", 
        false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

---

**Sample functionality:**

[image: UserControls TwoWay DataBinding]

Answer (score 0):

So I just learned how to properly use events I guess. Here's how the code looks now:

Main form:

```
public partial class main : Form
{
    public UCA uca;
    public UCB ucb;

    public delegate void passObject(object source, someObject u);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        uca = new UCA();
        ucb = new UCB();

        panel2.Controls.Add(uca);
        panel2.Controls.Add(ucb);

        ucb.Visible = false;
        uca.Visible = true;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uca.objectRequired += ucb.ucb_objectRequired;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucb.Visible = false;
        uca.Visible = true;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucb.Visible = true;
        uca.Visible = false;
    }
    
}
```

Usercontrol A:

```
public partial class UCA : UserControl
{
    public someObject o { get; set; }
    public event passObject objectRequired;
    
    public UCA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bUsage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Data is provided
        o = new someObject(data);
        usageRequired?.Invoke(this, o);
    }
 }
```

Usercontrol B:

```
public partial class UCB : UserControl
{
    public SomeObject o { get; set; }

    public UCDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }

    public void ucn_objectRequired(object sender, sObject u)
    {
        o = u;
        //Use the data from the object.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should redesign your data flow. UserControl should not usually make assumptions of what its parent would be, that's why it's a "customized control". It can be a `Form1` but not necessary.  So you shouldn't do casting like in your example.

To provide the information from A to B, one way is to create public Get/Set methods or properties for those controls. And the main form works with those public members, pseudo-code can be:

```cs
class main{
    UCA uca;
    UCB ucb;

    public void RefreshData(){
        object data = uca.GetData();
        ucb.UpdateData(data);
    }
}
```